# How does ctypes.c_int differs from ctypes.py_object?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, ctypes, pyobject

I understand that `multiplying` a `ctype` with an `integer` is `declaring an array.`

For example, `ctypes.c_int * 4` is an `array of 4 integers.`

Then what is `py_object`?

Please help me understand how does `ctypes.c_int` differs from `ctypes.py_object?`

Comment: `py_object` is a reference to a Python object.  For CPython, it is a `PyObject *`.

Comment: is it okay to say that `c_int` is a `child type` of `py_object` in `CPython`?

Comment: No, `c_int` is a wrapper for a C `int` and `py_object` is a wrapper for C `PyObject*`.  One is not derived from the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from ctypes import c_int, py_object

# Array of (three) integers initialized such that
# a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2, a[2] = 3. 
a = (c_int * 3)(1, 2, 3) 

# Array of (three) arbitrary Python objects initialized
# such that a[0] = "Pizza", a[1] = 5, a[2] = 5.813.
b = (py_object * 3)("Pizza", 5, 5.813)

print(a[:]) # -> [1, 2, 3]
print(b[:]) # -> ['Pizza', 5, 5.813]
```

Trying to execute

```
a = (c_int * 3)("Pizza", 5, 5.813)
```

will generate a `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`.

This is because we have specified that we want an array of three elements, all of which are integers, but we have attempted to include a string inside the array as well.

Arrays, unlike lists, require that all elements `a[0], a[1], ... , a[n]` are of the same type.

By specifying `py_object` instead of `c_int`, you are essentially permitted to have an array of arbitrary Python objects, as opposed to only integers.

Strictly speaking (in CPython), internally, the `py_object` way gives you an array of pointers to the `PyObject` datatype. Internally, all object types are extensions of `PyObject`.

So the type of all the elements of the `b` array is pointer to `PyObject`. A pointer is nothing more than a memory address. So every element of the `b` array is just a memory address pointing to some arbitrary object in Python. Internally, integer, floats, lists, dictionaries, and so on are all `PyObject`s so an array with elements of type `py_object` allows for its elements to be memory addresses that refer to essentially any kind of object in Python (lists, tuples, integers, floats, and so on).

When we print `b[0]`, for example, Python gives us `'Pizza'` as output. Internally, Python uses the memory address of the string object and returns the string for us.

Pointers / memory addresses are used frequently in C and in the CPython source code. Python essentially hides memory addresses from us as it is a high-level language, abstracting away from low-level concepts such as pointers.

I hope this helps!